# Python 3 support in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python-3

As python3 is getting standard more and more I wonder wether there is or will be support for python 3 in QGIS?

Answer (score 8):

Python 3.6 has landed in QGIS 2.99:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There will definitely be support for python 3 *at some point*. The big problem is that likely many of the plugins would need to be manually ported to work again and that is mostly out of the hands of QGIS developers. As such, it will be an unpleasant, but inevitable, moment in history. Maybe it will happen along with the other planned api breaks for 2.0, but [the developer mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer) is really your best bet.