# Versions of Python & QGIS for new user to both to install?

Tags: qgis, python, installation

I have used GIS (very basic functions), but now want to be able to customize to my needs.

My initial research leads me to believe that Python + QGIS is the way to go.

I understand that there are several plugins that will be useful along the way, but do not have enough knowledge to discern which ones and if they are all compatible with Python V3.

The install will be on Windows 7 machine.

Since I am learning Python and QGIS for the first time I want to use the newest versions possible-provided they (and their respective plug-ins) are compatible.

What versions of Python and QGIS should I, as a new user to both, install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QGIS installers (currently 2.4.0) include Python 2.7, and some parts of QGIS might not work with newer versions: [Python 3 support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28871/python-3-support-in-qgis)

The developers are still happy with Python2: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2012-September/022311.html (although this statement is almost 2 years old...)

The QGIS installation works independently from a Python version you may use outside QGIS.

Comment: What about ArcMap 10.1 or 10.2.2, do they work with Python 3.4.1 and vice versa?

Comment: Python 2.7 is going to be your best bet IMO for both.

Comment: Like Andre said, because QGIS installs it's own version of Python (for good or bad) you can still have different system Pythons installed.  I have 3.4, 2.6, 2.7 + the QGIS ones.

Comment: I don't have ArcMap, so I can't say which Python versions they support.

Comment: @Alešinar you should post this as a new question. There is a similar question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/609/will-arcgis-10-support-python-2-7-or-python-3-1) but it's 4 years old now and things might have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just download the "standalone installer" from https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html#windows and install that. As you work through the installation process, choose the parts you need. I particularly recommend getting the sample data.

Its simple and fun, so relax and enjoy it!